# Remove rows from recursive query

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

When I run this query in my database I get the following:

```
WITH RECURSIVE series AS (
    SELECT CONCAT( a.title) as str, a.prequelID
    FROM ( Prequels NATURAL JOIN Books) AS a
    UNION
    SELECT CONCAT(t.title, ' -> ', str) as str, t.prequelID
FROM (Books NATURAL JOIN Prequels) as t 
INNER JOIN series AS s ON s.prequelID = t.bookID
)
SELECT str as series FROM series
ORDER BY series;
```

This is the result :

[image]

I don't want any duplicates, only the full string that shows the whole series.
How do I do this?

**UPDATE**:

I updated the query because I realised I was missing the first book in the series.

```
WITH RECURSIVE series AS (
    SELECT CONCAT( a.title) as str, a.prequelID
    FROM ( Prequels NATURAL JOIN Books) AS a
    UNION
    SELECT CONCAT(t.title, ' -> ', str) as str, t.prequelID
FROM (Books NATURAL JOIN Prequels) as t 
INNER JOIN series AS s ON s.prequelID = t.bookID
)
SELECT CONCAT(a.title, ' -> ',a.str) as series
FROM (
SELECT Books.title, series.str
FROM series JOIN Books ON series.prequelID = Books.bookID
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT prequelID
        FROM Prequels
        WHERE series.prequelID = Prequels.bookID
) 
) a
ORDER BY series;
```

The result is still a bit off, since I only want the complete string of the series:
[image]

How do I fix this?

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Books
(bookID integer PRIMARY KEY,
title varchar(100),
pages integer);


CREATE TABLE Prequels
(bookID INTEGER REFERENCES Books(bookID),
prequelID INTEGER REFERENCES Books(bookID),
PRIMARY KEY (bookID,prequelID));
```

Sample data of the Game of Thornes series:

```
INSERT INTO BOOKS (bookID,title,pages) VALUES (80429,'A Game of Thrones',292);
INSERT INTO BOOKS (bookID,title,pages) VALUES (41121,'A Clash of Kings',160);
INSERT INTO BOOKS (bookID,title,pages) VALUES (29287,'A Storm of Swords',160);
INSERT INTO BOOKS (bookID,title,pages) VALUES (17696,'A Feast for Crows',292);
INSERT INTO BOOKS (bookID,title,pages) VALUES (3947,'A Dance with Dragons',101);


INSERT INTO Prequels (bookID,prequelID) VALUES (41121,80429);
INSERT INTO Prequels (bookID,prequelID) VALUES (29287,41121);
INSERT INTO Prequels (bookID,prequelID) VALUES (17696,29287);
INSERT INTO Prequels (bookID,prequelID) VALUES (3947,17696);
```

Comment: you need to provide sample data and desired output . ( maybe provide a fiddle)

Comment: Since you're joining on `prequelID`  and `bookID` and concatenating the strings, you may find length of the string, then find `MAX(length)` grouping by relevant ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to start from the roots of the trees.
There are no roots in the prequelId's.

```
WITH RECURSIVE series AS (
    SELECT 
      b.bookId
    , 1 as lvl
    , p.prequelID
    , CONCAT(b.title) as series
    FROM Books AS b
    LEFT JOIN Prequels AS p 
      ON p.bookId = b.bookId
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM Prequels p2
      WHERE p2.prequelID = b.bookId
    )
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT 
      s.bookId
    , s.lvl+1
    , p.prequelID
    , CONCAT(b.title, ' -> ', s.series)
    FROM series AS s
    JOIN Books AS b 
      ON b.bookId = s.prequelID
    LEFT JOIN Prequels AS p 
      ON p.bookId = s.prequelID
)
SELECT series
FROM series
WHERE prequelId is null
  AND lvl > 1
ORDER BY series;
```

| series |
| --- |
| A Game of Thrones -> A Clash of Kings -> A Storm of Swords -> A Feast for Crows -> A Dance with Dragons |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7ad8d1c1610b99c893c67d3bebfa70be)*

Comment: Won't include any books that don't have prequels (stand alone titles not part of a series). No idea if the op requires them or not.

Comment: Also, stops one book too early.  Should have 5 books in the series, not four. Recursive part needs to be `series INNER books LEFT prequels` (mistake inherited from OP).

Comment: Indeed. Made the same mistake as the OP. Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed now. To get those without prequels it just needs to be a LEFT JOIN at the end.

Comment: @TomLefher Thx, but I needed to improve it after Mat's fiddling.  The 2nd NOT EXISTS and CONCAT wasn't required after all. And now you can include books that are only in the book table, by removing the criteria on lvl.

Answer (score 1):

Modified version of LukStorms now deleted answer...

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4e26beed430aefb60f1dc91766db13d3

```
WITH RECURSIVE series AS (
   SELECT
      b.bookId,
      1 as lvl,
      p.prequelID,
      CONCAT(b.title)   AS series
    FROM
      books      b
    LEFT JOIN
      prequels   p
        ON p.bookid = b.bookid
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM Prequels p
      WHERE p.prequelID = b.bookId
    )

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      b.bookid,
      lvl+1,
      p.prequelID,
      CONCAT(b.title, ' -> ', s.series)
    FROM
      series     s
    INNER JOIN
      books      b
        ON b.bookid = s.prequelid
    LEFT JOIN
      prequels   p
        ON p.bookid = b.bookid
)
SELECT
  s.series
FROM
  series s
WHERE
  s.prequelid IS NULL
ORDER BY
  s.series;
```

The non recuraive part of the CTE has a LEFT JOIN so to include books that are not part of a series, just a standalone book. Revert that to NATURAL or INNER JOIN if you don't want that.

The non recursive part of the CTE has a WHERE clause to ensure it only ever starts from the last book in a series.

Thr recursive part of the CTE has a LEFT JOIN on the prequels table, so that the first book in a series isn't lost (due to not having a prequel row), and so records that book's prequel as NULL.

The outer query then looks for that NULL, so only outputting rows for completed series.

Comment: +1 for effort. Btw, it's not uncommon that someone temporarly deletes their answer to avoid downvotes while they are trying to fix their faulty solution.

Answer (score 0):

After the recursive query, you can compare all the *str* together with a self join, and keep the `s1.str` which are not a substring of any `s2.str` thanks to the `WHERE s2.str IS NULL` clause.

```
WITH RECURSIVE series AS (
    SELECT CONCAT( a.title) as str, a.prequelID
    FROM ( Prequels NATURAL JOIN Books) AS a
    UNION
    SELECT CONCAT(t.title, ' -> ', str) as str, t.prequelID
FROM (Books NATURAL JOIN Prequels) as t 
INNER JOIN series AS s ON s.prequelID = t.bookID
)
SELECT s1.str as series 
  FROM series AS s1
  LEFT JOIN series AS s2
    ON s2.str ~ s1.str
   AND s2.str <> s1.str
 WHERE s2.str IS NULL
ORDER BY series;
```

test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1713ee44c3bb8a5036984d17992e0eb2)

Comment: When I run this query, it gives zero rows :(  @Edouard

Comment: Sorry, there was `AND s2.str <> s1.str` missing in the `LEFT JOIN ... ON` clause. Answer has been updated, and should work as expected, see the result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1713ee44c3bb8a5036984d17992e0eb2).

Comment: Stops one book to early. Should include `Game of Thrones` but doesn't, due to mistake copied from OP. Recursive part of CTE needs to left join on to prequels.